# Combine 2 plots in one

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

$f: R^2 -> R,$ $f(x,y)=x²-y²$

```
VectorPlot[{2 x, -2 y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}] 
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors",
     PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I want both plots (`VectorPlot` and `ContourPlot`) shown in one figure. How to approach this ?

Comment: Take a look at Show.

Comment: have a look at `Show`

Comment: Please, if possible close this as a *duplicate* since it has surely been asked before.  That will assist me in correctly applying the `faq` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
PIC1 = VectorPlot[{2 x, -2 y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
PIC2 = ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
Show[PIC2, PIC1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Epilog` option

```
ContourPlot[z, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Epilog -> 
  First@
   VectorPlot[Evaluate@Grad[z, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
 ]
```

[image: Output of commands]

Answer (score 1):

The output of the Plot commands are Graphics objects which are by default shown graphically by the notebook interface -- but you are free to collect it and do other stuff.

Also, since you seem to be new to Mathematica: You can use `Grad` to compute the gradient.

```
z = x^2 - y^2;
Show[{
  ContourPlot[z, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}],
  VectorPlot[Evaluate@Grad[z, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
  }]
```

The `Evaluate` inside the `VectorPlot` tells Mathematica to evaluate this expression before starting to plot. Otherwise Mathematica would substitute specific values for `x` and `y` first, after which the gradient doesn't make much sense.

[image: Output of commands]